# Cycling through 2 objects in nunjucks

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I'm using node.js and MongoDB to create an app. I have 2 collections and you could say that they are in a 1:N relation.

```
col1 = { id="abc", name="London", createdAt=... }
col2 = { id="..." link="abc", temperature=31.24, sentAt=... }
```

I would like to create a table that would display it's name and temperature (the latest one, because there could be more)

```
Name    | Temperature
London  | 31.24
```

So I'm passing both objects from MongoDB into nunjucks where I'm trying to cycle through them like so:

```
{% for city in col1 %}
{% for data in col2 %}

{{ city.name }} | {{ data.temperature }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if I do this the result is this:

```
Name    | Temperature
London  | 31.24
London  | 31.24
```

And I know why that is but I don't really know how to fix it and I think that it has to have some common way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set data = {} %}
{% for city in col1 %}
  {% for data in col2 %}
    {% set data[city.name] = data.temperature %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for city, temperature in data %}
  {{city}} | {{temperature}}
{% endfor %}
```

---

But the best way is uniqued values outside of nunjucks template.